# How can we setup the proxy for wifi connection in Nexus S?

Tags: android, nexus-s

I just got a Nexus S. Because the internet connection at my place is using a proxy, I would to setup the proxy for this wifi connection. However, I cannot find the menu to setup the proxy for wifi connection. Can anybody please assist me on how to setup a proxy for a wifi connection please.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Joshua.

Comment: Sounds like a great question for android.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Yes please move it there if it is more appropriate to be in that forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Opera mobile, I could not find any other solution.

http://androidproxy.blogspot.com/